# Macro to read text till last row - 1

Tags: excel, copy, vba

I have a macro that Copies complete columns to another sheet.

Currently though, I need a Macro to only copy all the cells till the last ROW, but exclude the last ROW.

Example, If i have the following:

Cell A1 = 1, Cell A2 = 2, Cell A3 = 3, Cell A4 = Sum (A1:A3),Cell A5 = Blank

I want the macro to copy All the Cells A1, A2, and A3. So the logic i suppose would be to have the code run for all cells till blank (in this case A1 to A4), then exclude the last cell (A4) and copy everything above it
I am doing this for entire columns (A to E)
Thanks

The formula i have (very basic):

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set wbk4 = Workbooks.Open(MASTER)
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(WORKINGFILE)

wbk4.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E").Copy
wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XD1").PasteSpecial

wbk4.Close False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your last row is based on Column A you can try this:

```
Dim lrow As Long

With wbk4.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1", "E" & lrow - 1).Copy
    wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XD1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Comment: Stupid question, but what if i want to only copy the last row seperately? in my case (A5, B5, C5, D5, E5). Note that the last row is not constant (can increase or decrease based on data)?

Comment: No worries, got the second answer :) .Range("A" & lrow, "E" & lrow).Copy